# Xamarin.Android: TabLayout - Java.Lang.ClassCastException

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-tablayout, java.lang.class

In my App I am using a **TabLayout**. The Tabs for the Layout are added programmatically. In 99% of the cases it works fine, but every now and then I get a `Java.Lang.ClassCastException` while adding a tab. You cannot set a rule in which cases this occurs. It seems to be completely random.

Cleaning the solution and Rebuild helps every time, but I would still know, why this occurs and if there is any way to fix this bug.

[image]

Comment: Provide the stack trace

Comment: is there a kind of Stack Trace history in VS17 or do i have to wait until this bug happens again

Comment: You have to reproduce it :)

Comment: Reproduction is the only way my friend sorry!